# In bitbucket/git, what does "xx commits behind proto. Sync Now" do?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I've seen this message in bitbucket a couple times, for some feature branches that branched off from `proto`.

If I click `Sync Now`, what does it do?

[image: screeshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> so `Sync Now` would merge the all the new commits in `proto` into my current feature branch?

It is the "`Sync now`" feature presented in this [2018 thread](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Where-is-the-fork-sync-feature/qaq-p/786862#U787679) (initially for SVN, and for complaining that feature was not visible enough in the new BitBucket Cloud web UI).

In the case of "`x commits behind`" and Git, it would actually simply move the HEAD of your main branch (`master`) to the latest of the original repository.
Your `feature` branch should be unchanged (you can rebase it on top of `master` after sync if you want).